# CakePHP: Set up a new project within another project

Tags: cakephp

I've copied a homepage to the server, after a few problems with 1&1, if this matters, I've changed the .htaccess in the root, /app and /app/webroot directories. After

```
RewriteEngine on
```

I've included

```
RewriteBase /
```

to get it to work. However, beside the homepage itself, I've made an administration by adding a new CakePHP-project in the folder "Administration" which I've simply copied in the root-directory. Worked perfectly with XAMPP, but unfortunatly not with the 1&1-server. I've also tried to copy it in the app-folder, but visiting example.com/Administration will just give me an error, that says, the controller cannot be found.

Any ideas how I could access my administration?

Comment: Did you check the case on the folder you uploaded? 1and1 is case-sensitive.

Comment: Sorry, what exacly do you mean?

Comment: Did you name the folder "Administration" or "administration"? Case-sensitivity varies between Windows and 1and1 servers.

Comment: ah ok, sure it's "Administration" ;-)